# US ETF as EU investor (Ireland)

Tags: taxes, etf, ireland

At the start of this year the EU made it so we are unable to buy US domesticated ETFs in Europe.

I'm located in Ireland and domiciled there for tax purposes. We have to pay a 41% exit tax every 8 years now on EU domiciled versions of US ETFs. For more info on tax (https://www.irishtimes.com/business/personal-finance/don-t-invest-in-an-etf-until-you-understand-the-tax-1.3421331).

Our alternative is to open a US brokerage account where we will only pay 33% capital gains tax on eventual sale of the ETF, like with a normal stock. It is however quite difficult to find a broker who will take on an overseas client and those that do usually won't take deposits from Revolut or another low cost currency conversion third party. So for every deposit we have to take our bank's exchange rate on top of wire transfer fees.

What would your advice be in this situation? Is it worth paying the extra tax to avoid the headache? Or is it better to stick to stocks where we still only have to pay the 33%? There are also UK based investment trusts that offer the same kind of index tracking but at higher fees and when the UK leaves the EU this will no doubt create more problems.